# Sentence improvement : He summarily dismissed in a fit of rage what his son told him

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, exam-questions

> He summarily dismissed in a fit of rage what his son told him.

Or

> In a fit of rage he summarily dismissed  what his son told him.

Which of the two sentence is better than the other and why ?
This is actually a sentence improvement question asked in my exam, the actual given sentence was *He summarily dismissed what his son told him in a fit of rage.* I had four options, I managed to rule out two of them but not able to decide between the above given options.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for advice on writing style.

Comment: You don't say what the other two options are that you've apparently been able to rule out (on the grounds of *style*, or *syntax?*), but I would just say that there's nothing syntactically incorrect about, for example, *What his son told him he summarily dismissed in a fit of rage.* Come to that, there's nothing wrong with *What his son told him in a fit of rage he summarily dismissed,* but obviously that changes the meaning (it's the son rather than the father who got angry).

Comment: I think you may have eliminated the right answer. In the original, the son has the fit of rage.

Comment: What was the exam about? Writing style or learning English?

Answer (score 1):

In general in English, when a verb has an object, like "what his son told him" here, we put that object immediately after the verb. It is legal to put a prepositional phrase, like "in a fit of rage", in between, but this is generally considered awkward.

So where to put it? You can put it at the beginning of the sentence: "In a fit of rage, he summarily dismissed what his son told him." Or you can put it at the end: "He summarily dismissed what his son told him in a fit of rage." It's more common to put such phrases at the end so that the reader gets the basic idea of what's going on before adding the detail.